# How to copy metadata from avformat to avfilter module

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to receive some metadata from the dash stream and send this data to a ffmpeg filter. If I receive this metadata for each gop from the stream in the avformat/tiledashdec.c, how can I copy this data in the memory to avfilter? Any buffer in the data structure in ffmpeg I can use to hold this data, and which data structure can be accessed in both avformat and avfilter parts?

Comment: Add it as side data of strings metadata type to the packet. Then after decoding, transfer the side data as dictionary to avframe->metadata.

Comment: Thanks Gyan. I will try it. As I am a newbie on FFmpeg, is there any tutorial or example regarding to this process I can refer to?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51856505

Comment: Many thanks! I have fixed it. BTW, if I need to deal with a dash stream including video and metadata, I already prepared the binary metadata file for each segment, may I generate the mpd file with the metadata description as text? I also need to deal with the medadata receiving in tiledashdec.c, and do you know any example I can refer to how to receive the metadata and copy them from stream to memory? Thanks a lot! @Gyan